# Replicate data table rows conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a data table and need to conditionally add/duplicate the rows to create a new data table.

There is a due date column and given a range of dates, if a date within the range is in data table I just copy it to new table, if not I need to create a row, with same data but update due date and then copy it to new table.

Here is the scenario, given a date range of, say, 04/30 to 05/03:

```
SiteName   Due Date   Updater   SomeID
--------  ----------  -------   ------
Site1     2018-04-30   ABC      11870
Site1     2018-05-01   ABD      11870                
Site2     NULL         NULL     11871
```

I need to have in new table the following:

```
SiteName   Due Date   Updater   SomeID
--------  ----------  ------
Site1     2018-04-30   ABC      11870
Site1     2018-05-01   ABD      11870                
Site1     2018-05-02   NULL     11870
Site1     2018-05-03   NULL     11870
Site2     2018-04-30   NULL     11871                
Site2     2018-05-01   NULL     11871                
Site2     2018-05-02   NULL     11871                
Site2     2018-05-03   NULL     11871
```

In other words, if there is a non-null due date, copy it; if there is missing date(s), add it.

I tried looping in all different ways but kept getting multiple of each row.

Comment: The only way I could this was to get a parallel table from DB with no duplicates, no "Due Date", no "Updater" (all NULL), just Site Name and SomeID. Then loop through it and try to find a matching one in original table for each date in the range. If not found, update the due date field with the current date and add it to out table, if found it, just copy that row, with all its fields to out table. If there is a better and more efficient way to do it, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.